# Testing the `React.createRef` api with Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I would like to test the following class, which uses the `React.createRef` api.

A quick search didn't reveal any any examples of doing this though. Has anyone had success? How would I go about mocking the ref?

Ideally I'd like to use `shallow`.

```
class Main extends React.Component<Props, State> {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      contentY: 0,
    };

    this.domRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
    handleScroll();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
   window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
  }

  handleScroll = () => {
    const el = this.domRef.current;
    const contentY = el.offsetTop;
    this.setState({ contentY });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Wrapper innerRef={this.domRef}>
        <MainRender contentY={this.state.contentY} {...this.props} />
      </Wrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

**Update**

So I can test this using callback refs as follows

```
 setRef = (ref) => {
   this.domRef = ref;
 }

 handleScroll = () => {
   const el = this.domRef;
   if (el) {
     const contentY = el.offsetTop;
     this.setState({ contentY });
   }
 };

 render() {
   return (
     <Wrapper ref={this.setRef}>
       <MainRender contentY={this.state.contentY} {...this.props} />
     </Wrapper>
   );
 }
}
```

Then testing something like

```
it("adds an event listener and sets currentY to offsetTop", () => {
    window.addEventListener = jest.fn();
    const component = shallow(<ScrollLis />)
    const mockRef = { offsetTop: 100 };
    component.instance().setRef(mockRef);
    component.instance().componentDidMount();
    expect(window.addEventListener).toBeCalled();
    component.update();
    const mainRender = component.find(MainRender);
    expect(mainRender.props().contentY).toBe(mockRef.offsetTop);
  });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no specific routine for refs to be tested. A ref is just an object with `current` key.

In case it's accessed early in `componentDidMount`, lifecycle hooks need to be disabled for testing. A component should be tested that it initially has a ref, then it can be mocked

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Comp/>, { disableLifecycleMethods: true });
expect(wrapper.instance().domRef).toEqual({ current: null });
wrapper.instance().domRef.current = mockRef;
wrapper.instance().componentDidMount();
```

Since a ref is passed to another component as a prop, it can be tested that it was provided with correct ref:

```
expect(wrapper.find(Wrapper).dive().props().innerRef).toBe(wrapper.instance().domRef);
```

Then in `Wrapper` test can be tested that ref `current` key is assigned with correct object.

Comment: Ok so in my case `Wrapper` is just a styled component `div`. I need to give `this.domRef.current` an `offsetTop` to stop it erroring. Do you know how I'd do this?

Comment: I meant that Wrapper is tested like `const ref = { current: null }; const wrapperWrapper = shallow(<Wrapper innerRef={ref}; expect(ref.current).toBe(wrapperWrapper.instance())`. I'm not sure where offsetTop is involved.

Comment: React ensure that by the time handleScroll is called , `this.domRef.current` references the dom node, so has access to all its props where I'm using `offsetTop`. Its how to mock the dom node set by `React.createRef()`that I'm after

Comment: The test above errors on this line `const contentY = el.offsetTop;` when I'm testing the lifecycle methods

Comment: The question doesn't show why scroll event is triggered. But DOM events shouldn't be triggered in the first place in unit tests, especially global ones like scroll. Stub addEventListener and removeEventListener if needed. Any way, you need to mock a ref with an object that has offsetTop property in handleScroll test.

Comment: I've switched back to the callback api, so I can manually call the callback as this works, I'm still interested if its possible to do this with the `React.createRef` api though :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There's no magic behind React.createRef. It just creates `{current: null}` object in a declarative way. If you want to use real DOM refs then I'd advise against doing this with Enzyme unit tests.

Comment: It does assign the ref to the html node into the current prop automatically though? I've updated my question a little. Maybe the answer is that you should use callback refs if you want to test?

Comment: I see your point. There was no `handleScroll` in `componentDidMount`. Callback refs are deprecated and they don't add anything useful. You can mock a ref with ref object as well. See disableLifecycleMethods option, https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html#shallownode-options--shallowwrapper

Comment: I've just spotted your answer has updated to set the mockRef, will give that a go :)